# I can't get these divs to display horizontally

Tags: class, html, position

I'm having a problem displaying the `grid_8` blocks one after the other (horizontally).

The first 2 grid_8 divs go side by side but then the last one goes underneath... can anyone see if I'm doing something wrong in this code? If you need more information then please just ask and I'll post more code.

Thanks!

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="grid_24">
      <div class="wrapper indent-bottom8">
         <h3 class="title1 p4">Our Services</h3>
         <div class="grid_8">
            <div class="banner maxheight">
               <figure class="img-indent">
                  <img src="images/page1-img1.jpg" alt="">
               </figure>
               <h5><a href="services.html">RESIDENTIAL <br class="hide-tp">CLEANING</a></h5>
               Monoblock, concrete, driveways, slabbing, walls, garden furniture, forecourts and more...
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="grid_8">
            <div class="banner maxheight">
               <figure class="img-indent">
                  <img src="images/page1-img2.jpg" alt="">
               </figure>
               <h5><a href="services.html">COMMERCIAL <br class="hide-tp">CLEANING</a></h5>
               Shopping centres, loading bays, car parks, pathways, beer gardens and more...
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="grid_8 last-item">
            <div class="banner maxheight">
               <figure class="img-indent">
                  <img src="images/page1-img3.jpg" alt="">
               </figure>
               <h5><a href="services.html">CONSTRUCTION <br class="hide-tp">CLEANING</a></h5>
               Building sites, new build cleaning contracts. Anything that needs cleaned: give us a call!
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the CSS too?

Comment: without seeing any css, i suspect your parent div isnt long enough for all 3 so it is making it wrap, this usually happens if you have more padding/margins on the grid_8 divs then your widths allow for, or the incorrect width for each grid_8.

Comment: A css question is more relevant with css code provided, please fix your question. Nobody can help without any css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your CSS, I'm just guessing.  I would say you can try adding float:left to the divs.  Also, you should double-check your margins and padding to ensure that they aren't exceeding the width allowed.  If you have three 900px boxes with 10px padding, the width becomes 920px.

Comment: I'd rather say that without css there is no question at all., therefore there is no possible answers. But +1 for the guidelines :-)

Comment: Cheers mate, had a mess around with the sizes and it worked a treat.

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to place number of divs in horizontal rule then you have to define the float property and set it right, otherwise it will just form a vertical structure...

go to your css and define under grid_8 class property:

```
.grid_8
{
float:right;
}
```

this will arrange them in horizontal direction...